# Schema for DGML Generated out of VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-sdk

s there any new DGML xsd available other than http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml/dgml.xsd , as there is a difference in the codeMap.DGML generated from vs2017 to the xsd .

Answer (score 0):

Each version of VS ships their own version of this schema here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Xml\Schemas\1033\dgml.xsd